# Find the resulting speed and direction. Trig Problem involving resultant and vectors.

Tags: trigonometry, vector-spaces, solution-verification, vectors

> A barge is pulled by two tugboats. The first tugboat is traveling at a speed of 15 knots with heading 130°, and the second tugboat is traveling at a speed of 11 knots with heading 190°. Find the resulting speed and direction of the barge. (Round your answers to the nearest whole number.)

$$
|v+w|^2=15^2+11^2-2(15)(11)cos120
$$
$$
|v+w|^2=511
$$
$$
|v+w| = 22.60530911 = 23
$$
$$
sinB= 11sin(12)/22.60530911
$$
$$
SinB=0.421417792
$$
$$
B=25
$$
$$
130+25=155
$$

I'm getting a speed of $23$ knots and a direction of $155°$.  Is this correct?

Comment: So, after an hour, how long will the two tow cables be?  Twelve hours?

Comment: @User58220 Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: @user125736 Sorry to make you show your work, I found the error I made just a few seconds later.

Comment: @Goos No need to apologize! I am grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct.
\begin{align*}
x &= 15 \cos 130^\circ  + 11 \cos 190^\circ \approx -20.4746994 \text{ knots} \\
y &= 15 \sin 130^\circ  + 11 \sin 190^\circ \approx 9.5805366 \text{ knots} \\
r &= \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \approx 22.6 \text{ knots} \\
\theta &= 180^\circ + \arctan (y \; / \; x) \approx 154.9^\circ
\end{align*}

Comment: Since the barge is going faster than either of the tugs, it seems that the barge must be towing the tugs!!

Answer (score 0):

The question, and the OP's answer,(and the **up-voted, accepted answer**!), have the two tug-boats and the barge all travelling in different directions at different speeds. Thus, they must be getting steadily farther and farther apart.  How is this possible?  What does the diagram of the relative positions of the two tugs and the barge look like?  How long are the two tow-ropes, and what happens when the tugs run out of rope?

The question as stated is impossible to answer, as it does not describe vectors that can be added trigonometrically in any meaningful way

If the **velocities** of the two tugboats were replaced with **forces**, and we were asked to find the size and direction of the resultant **force** on the barge, then the work shown would be correct...

Comment: I agree something fishy is going on in the problem wording.  But this is mathSE and not physicsSE so I let it slide and assumed the obvious.

Comment: It's possible there was a confusion between the abbreviation for knots and kilonewtons...I would certainly like to see the original question...